# Connect to MySQL DB hosted in an AWS EC2 server

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2

I have developed a website with Flask, a python framework, deployed with nginx, which works fine. The website interacts with a MySQL database through pymysql and SQLAlchemy using the following URI:

```
"SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/database"
```

Both the website and the database are hosted in an AWS EC2 server. I am trying to access that database from my personal computer, establishing a connection with DBeaver. The [tutorial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-remote-access-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/) I am following says to set the bind-address found in the *mysqld.cnf* file to 0.0.0.0:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

However, doing so breaks the connection from the website with the database. This is the error found in the log:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') [SQL: ...]
```

Thus, I can't set the bind-address. The website works again when I comment it out. How can I keep the website working while allowing the remote access to the database?

Although I'm not sure how this helps, I have enabled the connection to the database in the AWS security group rules:

[image]

Any help or references regarding my problem are much appreciated. Stay safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql configuration can be left as it is. The access protocols are already defined in AWS. What I was missing was configuring a remote user for the database, with '%' as host (which means any host is OK). Then I just entered the DB connection credentials in DBeaver, and it worked!

I am not sure how secure the connection is. Leaving the user open to any connection is probably risky. However, I am not well-read in the matter and can't assess its security status. An SSL connection may be more secure, but I don't know how to configure it.